# devenv /installvstemplates very very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates

I would love to use VS templates more, but I find that creating and testing them is a bit of a pain.  One issue is that to refresh the templates you must run the command above, and it is very slow.

Another issue is that in order to edit templates, you basically use a text editor and then shove your files back into a ZIP archive, then run the install command again.  For a tool as advanced as VS2010, this seems ridiculously primitive.  And because of this, I will start making a template, then quit in favor of copy, paste and replace.

It is also a pain to store and share templates with a team.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your project as a [vsix package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff363239.aspx) instead, it will then install very fast.
Once installed you can uninstall the template just as fast by using the Visual Studio Extension Manager. The vsix also makes the templates easy to share with your team.

Regarding your other issue with editing the templates this is made easier if installing the Visual Studio SDK. It actually contains [templates for creating templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527340) so you can do it from within Visual Studio. It actually also simplifies the process of creating vsix packages.